# Excel Power Query joining all text files together, need them on separate rows Basic

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, power-query

I am importing many files in to excel. They are text files. Using PowerQuery They have about 40 lines of data in them, all on separate lines.

0945996
G ANDERSON
1405
Saturday 8th

etc etc

I want it to show going across so each line of data is in its own column - all across Row 1. So each text file has its data across the same Row, and lines of data in column A B C etc.

But when I import all the txt into power query, I click on content and it joins them all together so all the data from all files is in column A going all the way down. How to fix? Should look like (you might need to be on Desktop not mobile to view this properly):

`A             B        C         D
1 0945996    G ANDERSON    1405   Saturday 8th
2 0855686    A WATKINS     4774   Weds 4th
3 0644844    K WILSON      1855   Thursday 11th`

Comment: Are the data you want in columns on separate rows or are they separated by a character in the same cell?  If so, you `Text to Columns` feature in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I would first add an Index column, then select it and apply the Modulo calculation (Transform ribbon, Standard, Modulo).  Enter a value of 4 for the example above.

Then I would select the Index column and apply a Pivot (Transform ribbon, Pivot column).  I would choose your Column A as the "Values" setting, and in the Advanced settings I would choose "Don't Aggregate".

This assumes/relies on every "record" being input as the same number of rows (e.g. 4).